# Mixing mime types with HTTPServer in python

Tags: python, html, css, mime-types

Right now I have this file structure

```
server-
      |
      |css-
      |   |bad.css
      |
      |html-
      |    |bad.html
      |
      |jpg-
      |      |bad.jpg
      |
      |server.py
```

this is bad.css:

```
body
{
    background-image:url('bad.jpg');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:right top;
    margin-right:200px;
}
```

this is bad.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bad.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>This isn't a thing!</h1>
    <p>You must be mistaken. But <a href="/index">here</a> is where you can find your way again.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

this is the relevant part of server.py

```
from BaseHTTPServer import BaseHTTPRequestHandler as Handler
from mime types import guess_type

class MyHandler(Handler):
    def do_GET(self):
        print self.path
        print self.headers
        extensions = ['html', 'css', 'jpg']
        fname = self.path
        for ext in extensions:
            if fname.endswith(ext):
                fname = ext + fname
                break
        if fname.split('/')[0] == '':
            fname = 'html/bad.html'
        mimetype = guess_type(fname)[0]
        print fname
        data = open(fname, 'rb')
            self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-type', mimetype)
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(data.read())
        data.close()
```

My updated code should have fixed it, but now my browser doesn't render it at all, it just shows html code.
[image: Screen shot of what I am seeing]

Comment: First of all, what's the problem, you said `From what I've gathered via google, the problem is with ...`, what "problem" were you researching on on Google?

Comment: @vikki http://stackoverflow.com/questions/947372/custom-simple-python-http-server-not-serving-css-files
the problem is that none of the css is rendering. when i point my browser at my server, i don't see the image, only the html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why your css and images won't load is because your handler doesn't know how to handle the request(s) for those files. Here is a simple example copied (and tweaked abit) from nosklo's answer in the question you linked to.

```
def do_GET(self):
    try:
        if self.path in ("", "/"):
            filepath = "html/bad.html"
        else:
            filepath = self.path.lstrip("/")

        f = open(os.path.join('.', filepath), "rb")

    except IOError:
        self.send_error(404,'File Not Found: %s ' % filepath)

    else:
        self.send_response(200)

        #this part handles the mimetypes for you.
        mimetype, _ = mimetypes.guess_type(filepath)
        self.send_header('Content-type', mimetype)
        self.end_headers()
        for s in f:
            self.wfile.write(s)
```

**NB:** You will have to change the css link in your html from

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/bad.css">
```

to

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/bad.css">
```

Comment: @Broseph see my update. Take note of how we are opening the file, ive added the `rb` flag to open the files in binary mode, without this any images won't display.

Comment: I made changes but still no dice. Should the css link be href="bad.css" ?

Comment: Shouldn't `fname = ext + fname` actually be `fname = fname + ext`

Comment: also, leave the links in the css as they were, i.e `background-image:url('../images/bad.jpg')`

Comment: The files are in folders based on their extensions. I didn't change their organization.

Comment: In that case you are appending file paths the wrong way, please use `os.path.join(ext, fname)` , otherwise you get something like "cssbad.css" instead of "css/bad.css".

Comment: self.path always starts with a '/' .

Comment: I renamed that folder to jpg, I forgot to mention that.

Comment: This line will always return true `if fname.split('/')[0] == '':` Therefore anything you do before it is going to be ignored. Try the code in my answer it works and is easier to read.

Comment: I found the error. I wasn't doing `self.send_response(200)`. That line you mentioned is only true if the requested file doesn't have an extension in the list. Everything works now though!